# More efficient sorting for pairs of files

Tags: java, sorting

I have a folder with pairs of files. Pairs share filename but have different extension (in this case, they are pairs of .txt and .png). I am looking to store them into a HashMap< File, File > by pairs. Here is what I did to find the pairs:

```
LinkedList<File> fileList = new LinkedList<File>(Arrays.asList(fileArray));
LinkedList<File> alreadyCompared = new LinkedList<File>();

HashMap<File, File> filePairs = new HashMap<File, File>();

for (Iterator<File> itr1 = fileList.iterator(); itr1.hasNext(); ) {

    File comparator = itr1.next();

    if (!alreadyCompared.contains(comparator)) {

        String stringComparator = comparator.getName().split("\\.")[0];
        alreadyCompared.add(comparator);

        for (Iterator<File> itr2 = fileList.iterator(); itr2.hasNext(); ) {

            File compared = itr2.next();

            if (!alreadyCompared.contains(compared)) {

                String stringCompared = compared.getName().split("\\.")[0];

                if (stringComparator.equals(stringCompared)) {

                    if (comparator.getName().endsWith("txt")) {

                        filePairs.put(comparator, compared);

                    } else {

                        filePairs.put(compared, comparator);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return filePairs;
```

Now, this takes *a lot of time* when I have more than 1000 files to sort, and I'd like to find a more efficient way of doing it. What other way can I sort these files?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am a little lost.  Is the problem to just group the files with the same names (ignoring extension)?

Comment: Just guessing, if you assume the files you have in txt are in png, why to compare all of them and not retrieve the png directly?

Comment: Why store the files at all? Why not store the names of the files then get them as needed?

Comment: @ChrisK, I need to group them by filename but it's important to know which file is a text file and which is a PNG.

Comment: @KBorja I do not understand your question, mind to repeat it?

Comment: @brso05 Same as above, I don't get what you're saying. What are you suggesting?

Comment: @Laura in that case is there any need to sort at all?  This feels like a school task, so I am going to refrain from adding an answer.  However consider populating a map in a single pass;  where the map is fileNameWithoutTag -> Tuple(txtFile,pngFile).  That would not require any sorting or nested loops, and thus would be very fast.

Comment: @ChrisK That looks viable, but the problem is I do not know the filenames before I populate the map.

Comment: @Laura that is fine, you can build the map up one piece at a time while you loop over the incoming files.  You just need a representation for 'I have not seen that file yet' as either the txt file or the png file could be found first.  That is, at any point in time the map entry awesomePic1 could point at null, or (awesomePic1.txt,null) or (null, awesomePic1.png) or (awesomePic1.txt, awesomePic1.png).

Comment: What I meant, maybe I'm loosing something, is that you can get all files ending with .txt, then loop over them and with the "filename.txt" just load "filename.png" without two loops.

Comment: @KBorja forgot to mention the pairs might not exist and there might  be only one png or txt with a certain name. My mistake :)

Comment: And what is suppose to happen in those cases? nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting them in an unordered `Map` like `HashMap`, I would put the elements in a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) because it sorts it's keys.

Per the linked Javadoc,

> A Red-Black tree based [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) implementation. The map is sorted according to the [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of its keys, or by a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Comment: I do not need to have them in a special order, I just need them to be paired. How do you suggest I do that using a TreeMap?

Answer (score 0):

I made up a bit of code to illustrate my comment.

```
HashMap<File, File> filePairs = new HashMap<File, File>();

File dir = new File("your files directory");
File [] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".txt");
    }
});

String fileName = "";

for (File txtFile : files) {
    fileName = txtfile.getName().split("\\.")[0];
    pngFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + fileName + ".png");

    if (pngFile.exists()) {
        filePairs.put(txtFile, pngFile);
    }
}
```